# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus application question

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question that I believe I have the solution to, but I am not sure and there is no way of checking. As such I was hoping someone could look over my solutions and provide me with some feedback. The question is as follows:

$(a)$ Suppose that $f(x)$ is differentiable for all values of $x$, and that $f(1) = 0$ and $f'(1)<0$. Determine which of the following statements are true for the function $$\int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt$$ taking care to give reasons for your answers.

$(i)$ $F$ is a twice differentiable function of $x$

$(ii)$ $F$ and $dF/dx$ are both continuous

$(iii)$ $F$ has a local maximum at $x=1$

$(b)$ Find $$\int^{\pi\over 6}_{^3\sqrt x}cos(t^3)dt$$

For part $(a)$ I used the first part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that tells me that $\frac{d}{dx}\int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt=f(x)$, and $f(x)$ has been defined as differentiable in the question. Hence $(i)$ is true. Then, if $(i)$ is true, $(ii)$ must also be true as we have seen $F$ and $dF/dx$ are differentiable, and in order to be differentiable they must first be continuous. Finally, $(iii)$ is also true as $f'(1)<0$.

For part $(b)$, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells me that $\int^{\pi\over 6}_{^3\sqrt x}cos(t^3)dt=cos((\pi/6)^3)-cos((^3\sqrt x)^3)$ which gives me $cos(\frac{\pi^3}{216})-cos(x)$.

Comment: for part (a), do you mean to define $F(x)=\int^{x}_{0}f(t)dt$ and (b) as $F(x)=\int^{\pi\over 6}_{^3\sqrt x}cos(t^3)dt$?

Comment: The question doesn't define it that way, but I intended to do so myself.

Comment: For (a)(iii), don't forget the Critical Point Test (aka First Derivative Test) for local maximums.

Comment: I think for part b you have the following result instead: $(x^{1/3})'\cos(x)$ with a minus before it.

Comment: @Babaxor By $(x^{1/3})'$ do you mean the derrivative? And in that case would that make the solution $cos(\frac{\pi^3}{216})-\frac{1}{3}x^{2/3}cos(x)$?

Comment: see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: Looking at your solutions for (i) (might be a typo here? Probably a missing differentiation? $F=f$ is obviously not true in general since $F(0)=0$, but $f(0)$ can be anything) and (b) (the fundamental theorem *does not* state $\int_a^b f(t)dt=f(b)-f(a)$!), you should have a second look at the precise formulation of the fundamental theorem of calculus or provide the version you are using. For (iii), you also need to mention that $F'(1)=f(1)=0$ (along with $F''(1)=f'(1)<0$ which you already noticed).

Comment: @Piwi Ah yes you are correct; (i) was a typo and I was indeed missing a differentiation. For part (b) you are right, the Fundamental Theorem states that $\int^{b}_{a}f(t)dt=F(b)-F(a)$, I think (please confirm!). Of course for part (iii) the addition of the first derrivative test is quite sensible, thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's the correct statement from the theorem (or one of its corollaries) where $F$ is any differentiable function such that $F'=f$ (i.e. an antiderivative) (so $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is a possible choice if $f$ is continuous, but not the only choice - just saying to avoid confusion with the $F$ you already defined elsewhere). So to solve (b), your first task and also the main action is to find $F$, the rest should be easy then.